# Plotting data from an svm fit - hyperplane

Tags: r, svm

I used svm to find a hyperplane best fit regression dependent on q, where I have 4 dimensions: x, y, z, q.

```
fit <- svm(q ~ ., data=data,kernel='linear')
```

and here is my fit object:

```
Call:
svm(formula = q ~ ., data = data, kernel = "linear")


Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  C-classification 
 SVM-Kernel:  linear 
       cost:  1 
      gamma:  0.3333333 

Number of Support Vectors:  1800
```

I have a 3d plot of my data, where the 4th dimension is color, using plot3d. How can I overlay the hyperplane that svm found? How can I plot the hyperplane? I'd like to visualize the regress hyperplane.

Comment: Um....1 response, 1 covariate: best fit line. 1 response, 2 covariates: best fit plane. 1 response, 3 covariates: ?.

Comment: @joran: I would say the answer is "small multiples" or coplots: supposing we have predictors (x,y,z) and response w, plot the (x,y,w) dividing plane in a number of subplots for regions (z1,z2), (z2,z3) ... -- not trivial though.  That or use dynamic graphics a la ggobi ...

Comment: I wonder, who minused CodeGuy. Even, if it is 10-dimensional, this question could be meant as *how should I visualize this, etc.*. more over, there are publications devoted to high-dimensinal visualization.

Comment: @joran: This isn't too odd nor unusual given a classification context.  In a 2-D plane, one can have positive and negative instances that are split by a line, so there is 1 response, 2 predictors, and one can color the points based on whether these are negative/positive (or 0/1) outcomes.  For 3 predictors, 3 dimensional space to plot the predictors and one can color or shade the points based on the response.  In other words, the response need not increase the algebraic dimensionality.

Comment: @CodeGuy Like Max, I think you are doing classification, not regression.  If this is not the case, can you please include the output of `str(data)` and `summary(data)`?

Comment: @Iterator I agree totally (and with Ben+Max's points). But the OP's previous question was rather pointedly about regression (despite their code signifying otherwise), and when shown examples for how to produce a separating hyperplane in 3-space rather pointedly responded that they wanted the _regression_, "best fit" hyperplane. So my comment was meant as a gentle nudge to think carefully about what exactly they wanted. In any case, the questions have elicited some excellent answers.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You wrote:

> I used svm to find a hyperplane best fit regression

But according to:

```
Call:
svm(formula = q ~ ., data = data, kernel = "linear")

Parameters:
SVM-Type:  C-classification
```

you are doing *classification*.

So, first of all decide what you need: to classify or to fit regression, from `?svm`, we see:

```
type: ‘svm’ can be used as a classification machine, as a
      regression machine, or for novelty detection.  Depending of
      whether ‘y’ is a factor or not, the default setting for
      ‘type’ is ‘C-classification’ or ‘eps-regression’,
      respectively, but may be overwritten by setting an explicit
      value.
```

As I believe you didn't change the parameter `type` from its default value, you are probably solving `classification`, so, I will show how to visualize this for classification.

Let's assume there are `2` classes, generate some data:

```
> require(e1071) # for svm()                                                                                                                                                          
> require(rgl) # for 3d graphics.                                                                                                                                                                                    
> set.seed(12345)                                                                                                                                                                     
> seed <- .Random.seed                                                                                                                                                                
> t <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100), z=runif(100), cl=NA)
> t$cl <- 2 * t$x + 3 * t$y - 5 * t$z                                                                                                                                                 
> t$cl <- as.factor(ifelse(t$cl>0,1,-1))
> t[1:4,]
           x         y         z cl
 1 0.7209039 0.2944654 0.5885923 -1
 2 0.8757732 0.6172537 0.8925918 -1
 3 0.7609823 0.9742741 0.1237949  1
 4 0.8861246 0.6182120 0.5133090  1
```

Since you want `kernel='linear'` the boundary must be `w1*x + w2*y + w3*z - w0` - hyperplane.
Our task divides to 2 subtasks: 1) to evaluate equation of this boundary plane 2) draw this plane.

1) **Evaluating the equation of boundary plane**

First, let's run `svm()`:

```
> svm_model <- svm(cl~x+y+z, t, type='C-classification', kernel='linear',scale=FALSE)
```

I wrote here explicitly `type=C-classification` just for emphasis we want do *classification*.
`scale=FALSE` means that we want `svm()` to run directly with provided data without scaling data (as it does by default). I did it for future evaluations that become simpler.

Unfortunately, `svm_model` doesn't store the equation of boundary plane (or just, normal vector of it), so we must evaluate it. From [svm-algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Dual_form) we know that we can evaluate such weights with following formula:

```
w <- t(svm_model$coefs) %*% svm_model$SV
```

The negative intercept is stored in `svm_model`, and accessed via `svm_model$rho`.

2) **Drawing plane**.

I didn't find any helpful function `plane3d`, so, again we should do some handy work. We just take grid of pairs `(x,y)` and evaluate the appropriate value of `z` of the boundary plane.

```
detalization <- 100                                                                                                                                                                 
grid <- expand.grid(seq(from=min(t$x),to=max(t$x),length.out=detalization),                                                                                                         
                    seq(from=min(t$y),to=max(t$y),length.out=detalization))                                                                                                         
z <- (svm_model$rho- w[1,1]*grid[,1] - w[1,2]*grid[,2]) / w[1,3]

plot3d(grid[,1],grid[,2],z)  # this will draw plane.
# adding of points to the graphics.
points3d(t$x[which(t$cl==-1)], t$y[which(t$cl==-1)], t$z[which(t$cl==-1)], col='red')
points3d(t$x[which(t$cl==1)], t$y[which(t$cl==1)], t$z[which(t$cl==1)], col='blue')
```

We did it with `rgl` package, you can rotate this image and enjoy it :)

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you so much. However, I wanted to do a regression. Could you provide code for this? Again, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I'm just starting out in R myself, but there's a decent tutorial on using the e1071 package in R for *regression* rather than classification:

http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~ricco/tanagra/fichiers/en_Tanagra_Support_Vector_Regression.pdf

with a zip file of the test dataset and R script in:

http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~ricco/tanagra/fichiers/qsar.zip

Skip the first section on Tanagra and head straight to section 6 (page 14).  It has its faults, but it gives examples of using R for linear regression, SVR with epsilon-regression and with nu-regression.  It also makes a stab at demonstrating the tune() method (but could be done better, IMHO).

*(Note: if you choose to run the examples in that paper, don't bother trying to find a working copy of xlsReadWrite -- it's much easier to export qsar.xls as a .csv file and just use read.csv() to load the dataset.)*