# Can I plot the SVM decision boundary for 3 features(in 3D space) using Scikit learn?

Tags: plot, 3d, scikit-learn, svm

I am using scikit-learn to understand Support Vector Machines(SVM). I want to plot the decision boundary computed by SVM. The SVM uses 3 features. So the decision boundary must be drawn in 3D space. Is this possible using scikit-learn? 
I could find only 2D plots of SVM decision boundary at the official website. 
However I found links on stackoverflow which show this is possible using [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146212/how-to-plot-a-hyper-plane-in-3d-for-the-svm-results)   and [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017427/plotting-data-from-an-svm-fit-hyperplane). Is there a way in which I can achieve the same using scikit-learn?

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 4):

You don't use scikit-learn to plot things in Python. You have to use another package, and if you check scikit-learn's examples, you will see they use matplotlib. You can create 3D plots with matplotlib, [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) is the tutorial. The usage is basically the same than in 2D, except you add an argument for the third dimension.

Another popular package you could use is [mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html), which was conceived especially for 3D plotting.

Comment: Yes I accept that for 3D plot I have to use matplotlib. However my question was can I plot the decision boundary of the SVM when using 3 features? In the examples shown, they show the usage of 2D plot(because they use 2 features) for showing the  decision boundary. I could not find an example where they use 3 features and show the decision boundary.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. Take this example (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html). If you have 3 features, all you have to do is add a z coordinate to your meshgrid defined similarly as x and y and pass it to your predict method and contourf method.

Comment: Great! This is what I wanted to know; how to add the z coordinate to the plot. I am going to try it.